# What's the purpose of the Google camera adapter drivers?

Tags: video, google-voice

I understand these get installed when installing Google Voice and Video Chat, but why are they there and what does Google use them for?

Comment: They're also needed to use Hangouts in Google+.

Answer (score 1):

They get installed, so that Google Talk can talk to your Webcam & Microphone subsystems.

Comment: But there're standard APIs for talking to webcams and microphones in all major operating systems so that applications don't have to install specialized drivers. Using a driver for this is quite weird.